# AllRound Automations Msg: "Using a filter for all users can lead to poor performance!"

Tags: oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

- O.S.: Windows Server 2008 R2 (Amazon Web Service VM)
- Oracle: 11g 11.2.0.4.0 (64b)
- PL/SQL Devel Ver: 12.0.2.1818 (64b)

Today when I connect with PL/SQL Developer I see the following message:

> "Using a filter for all users can lead to poor performance!"

There is an option "Don't show this message again" but I am not enabling that while I work to understand what this message is trying to communicate.

I have googled the message, but the only return I am seeing specific to that message is in Japanese and I am not fully following what Google Translate is showing me.

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1946659678070468148.html&prev=search

I think it is advising that it is a non-critical message focused on browser filters that probably do not apply to my uses, however it also directs to a "Browser Filter" setting in the Tools menu I am not finding in my PL/SQL Developer install.

Can anyone add insight, experience or detail to this message and it's meaning(s)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is a warning about the fact you have chosen "All Users" in the filtering options of the object browser view:

It is warning you that browsing the objects tree could be very slow because it will show all objects in the whole oracle installation, not just those created by you.

You get this warning also on program startup because pl/sql developer remembers this setting.

[image]

Comment: Terrific response and explanation!  Thank you!!

My current local PL/SQL instance(s) actually show <CURRENT USER> (rather than the <ALL USERS> mentioned here, but I also haven't seen the message for several days now.  Perhaps I had an odd setting on the login that I've unknowing "re-set"?

In any case it's a great response that undoubtedly will help someone else along the way.